# Trying to complete complex queries, having trouble with them

Tags: sql, sql-server

[These are the tables that I have created for my Database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kuv0.png)

I am trying to ask it a few queries but they are not seeming to work no matter what I enter. I am trying to find out the following:

my first was:

`select league, teamID from team, player, where Team.Player = Player.PlayerId`
the output was an error message 207

What player has the lowest salary, what is his address, first and last name? 
What League and Region is Player # 100 playing in?
How many players are currently in each region?
What teams has Player # 104 played for since 2014?

all of the SQL I have written to create this is below:

```
CREATE TABLE Team (
  TeamID INT NOT NULL,
  Team VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  League VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  Region VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TeamID))

INSERT INTO Team (TeamID, Team, League, Region) VALUES (12, 'Rays', 'American', 'East');
INSERT INTO Team (TeamID, Team, League, Region) VALUES (13, 'Giants', 'National', 'West');
INSERT INTO Team (TeamID, Team, League, Region) VALUES (14, 'Dodgers', 'National', 'West');
INSERT INTO Team (TeamID, Team, League, Region) VALUES (15, 'Blue Jays', 'American', 'East');
INSERT INTO Team (TeamID, Team, League, Region) VALUES (16, 'Royals', 'American', 'Central');

CREATE TABLE TEAMPLAYER (
  TeamID INT NOT NULL,
  PlayerID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  EndDate DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TeamID, PlayerID))

INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (12, '100', '01/01/2013', NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (13, '101', '03/05/2014', NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (14, '102', '09/01/2013', NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (15, '103', '09/01/2013', '12/31/2013');
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (16, '104', '06/23/2015', NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (16, '103', '01/01/2014', NULL);
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (12, '104', '03/05/2014', '06/22/2015');
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (14, '103', '01/01/2008', '08/31/2013');
INSERT INTO TEAMPLAYER (TeamID, PlayerID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (15, '102', '05/05/2010', '08/31/2013');

CREATE TABLE Player (
  PlayerID INT NOT NULL,
  PlayerLName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PlayerFName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  HomeAddress VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  Salary INT NOT NULL,
  AgentID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID))

INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, PlayerLName, PlayerFName, HomeAddress, Salary, AgentID) VALUES (100, 'Jones', 'Larry', '1421 Rovetta Way', 500000, 35);
INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, PlayerLName, PlayerFName, HomeAddress, Salary, AgentID) VALUES (101, 'Armstrong', 'Sam', '221 Sovereign', 500000, 35);
INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, PlayerLName, PlayerFName, HomeAddress, Salary, AgentID) VALUES (102, 'Jones', 'David', '3333 Skip St', 300000, 34);
INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, PlayerLName, PlayerFName, HomeAddress, Salary, AgentID) VALUES (103, 'Ortiz', 'David', '1111 Jones Ave', 1400000, 36);
INSERT INTO Player (PlayerID, PlayerLName, PlayerFName, HomeAddress, Salary, AgentID) VALUES (104, 'Davis', 'Chris', '1111 Jones Ave', 1100000, 38);

CREATE TABLE Agent (
  AgentID INT NOT NULL,
  AgentLName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  AgentFName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  AgentAddress VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  Phone BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (AgentID))

INSERT INTO Agent (AgentID, AgentLName, AgentFName, AgentAddress, Phone) VALUES (34, 'Brown', 'Harry', '100 Smart Way', 2135552222);
INSERT INTO Agent (AgentID, AgentLName, AgentFName, AgentAddress, Phone) VALUES (35, 'Griffey', 'Ken', '150 Leaping Lizard', 2485332391);
INSERT INTO Agent (AgentID, AgentLName, AgentFName, AgentAddress, Phone) VALUES (36, 'Brown', 'Norma', '175 Hartford', 5863435932);
INSERT INTO Agent (AgentID, AgentLName, AgentFName, AgentAddress, Phone) VALUES (37, 'Armstrong', 'Deb', '1210 Clifton', 8505756157);
INSERT INTO Agent (AgentID, AgentLName, AgentFName, AgentAddress, Phone) VALUES (38, 'Armstrong', 'Ken', '1210 Clifton', 8505756158);
```

Comment: Provide an example of your queries that aren't working, and what error you are getting with them.

Comment: Can you show us the queries you've written so far, and what their output is?

Comment: At the very least, tag the proper RDBMS, and supply data tables inside your question. Start [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Error 207 seems to be "invalid column name". You'll need to show us your table structure for us to know. Also, please add the query to your question (instead of in a comment).

Comment: `Team.Player` is not a valid column according to your image...

Comment: thanks Ryan, so far for the query that is asking where the player 100 is playing in, I wrote  select league, region from team where teamid = '12'  but I need to reference the players ID number (100) would I need to use a join statement for this or can I just add it into it with more parameters

Comment: Just so you understand, you are working with database 101 queries, this question is an examples of an actual complex query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708900/sql-server-query-performace

Answer (score 1):

Your first select query has an extra comma but it uses a very poor coding technique called an implicit join. There is no circumstance where you should ever use those. Try:

```
select league, teamID from team
inner join  player 
on Team.Player = Player.PlayerId
```

All of the other queries are pretty simple if you use joins. If you don't know how to do that then read up on them and get to know them thoroughly. You can't ever effectively query without understanding joins.